# Data from mysql in ejs but only get [object Object]

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I only get `[object Object]` when I use EJS to render the data from MySQL. JSON.parse does not work as well with this string: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

```js
app.get("/favorites", function(req, res) {
  var favorites = {};
  db.query("SELECT * FROM favs WHERE user_id = '1'", function (error, result, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    favorites = result;
    res.render("favorites", {data: {print: favorites, page: true}});
  });
});
```

```html
console.log("<%= data.print %>");
<!-- [object Object] -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object. You don't need to `parse` it, but to `stringify` it:

```
res.render("favorites", JSON.stringgify({data: {print: favorites, page: true}}));
```